# Nunca entra al if si la condición es n1 == 759,55

Tags: javascript

Tengo un código donde hago un if y resulta que nunca entra cuando la condición es `n1 == 759,55` y no sé por qué.

Lo que quiero es que cuando la variable n1 sea de 759,55 y cumpla con el resto, entre, pero no lo hace.

```js
document.querySelector('#calcular').addEventListener('click', () =>{
  const n1 = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#select').value);
  const n2 = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#selectDos').value);
  const n3 = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#selectTres').value);

  let r;














 if(n1 == 415,35  && n2== 1 && n3 == 1){
    r = "26,70";
  }else if( n1 == 415,35  && n2== 2 && n3 == 1){
    r = "40,05" ;
  }else if(n1 == 415,35  && n2==3  && n3 ==1 ){
    r = "66,75";
  }else if(n1 == 415,35  && n2== 1 && n3 ==2 ){
    r ="35,60" ;
  }else if(n1 == 415,35  && n2== 2 && n3 ==2 ){
    r ="53,40" ;
  }else if(n1 == 415,35  && n2== 3 && n3 ==2 ){
      r ="89,00" ;
  }else if(n1 == 415,35  && n2== 1 && n3 ==3 ){
    r ="53,40" ;
  }else if(n1 == 415,35  && n2== 2 && n3 ==3 ){
    r ="80,10" ;
  }else if(n1 == 415,35  && n2== 3 && n3 ==3 ){
    r ="133,51" ;
  }else if(n1 == 759,55  && n2== 1 && n3 == 1){
      r = "21,16";
    }else if( n1 == 759,55  && n2== 2 && n3 == 1){
      r = "31,74" ;
    }else if(n1 == 759,55  && n2==3  && n3 ==1 ){
      r = "52,91";
    }else if(n1 == 759,55  && n2== 1 && n3 ==2 ){
      r ="28,22" ;
    }else if(n1 == 759,55  && n2== 2 && n3 ==2 ){
      r = "42,33" ;
    }else if(n1 == 759,55  && n2== 3 && n3 ==2 ){
        r = "70,54" ;
    }else if(n1 == 759,55  && n2== 1 && n3 ==3 ){
      r = "42,33" ;
    }else if(n1 == 759,55  && n2== 2 && n3 ==3 ){
      r = "63,49" ;
    }else if(n1 == 759,55  && n2== 3 && n3 ==3 ){
      r = "105,81" ;
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Por cierto, al dar a Ejecutar al snippet que agregaste, hay un error (falta cerrar una llave al parecer). Verifica que el código esté bien escrito para lograr reproducir el error. ¡Y no olvides agregar el HTML!

Answer (score 0):

En javascript, los decimales se indican con un punto, no una coma.
Por ejemplo:

```js
var a=759.55;
if (a==759.55) console.log ("Si");
else console.log("No");
```

Comment: @aitor09 No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) esta respuesta. Se asume que te fue útil, ya que [en tu otra pregunta](/q/571768) el código ya está cambiado.